# Dynamic wiring in linked block

Tags: matlab, simulink

The problem:

In my simulink model, I have a bus creator that will send all the signals to a block. The block purpose is to make a selector and a switch dynamically based on an index. Example : I have 3 objects, each with a position and a velocity signal, and I want to get the position of the 3 objects, so 3 signals (this means the bus selector will have 3 output and the multi switch will have 4 (one for the index)). The block is working correctly, with a recursive function script called in the callback, it checks the bus for all possible signals and count the number of objects, and modifies the bus selector and the switch accordingly. The problem is that this block is linked to a library, so I have to disable the link in order for the callback script to work.

The questions:

1. What should i change in order to avoid disabling the link?
2. Is there another way of making dynamic wiring and don't use a callback script?

Comment: PS: you can also try to tick the check box `Allow library block to modify its contents`: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/create-dynamic-masked-subsystems.html. Not sure if that will work in your case, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a using [vector concatenation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/slref/vectorconcatenate.html) block instead of bus creator plus a [matlab function](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block to choose. Here is the model

[image]

and here is the code in matlab function:

[image]

In this way the block in the library does not need to change each time. Also if you have to keep your buses you can use a [bus to vector](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/slref/bustovector.html) block to convert them to vector.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using a [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block to do the selecting is a good one, but I would try and stay with a Bus input to preserve the advantages of working with busses, rather than convert to vector and back. So instead of having your code as a callback to the bus selector block, my suggestion would be to implement it in a MATLAB Function block with a bus input and the signal input used to do the selection in the bus, and define the output still as a bus object.